# How does one change fonts in web pages for Android?

Tags: android, fonts

I'm making a simple browser based game using Javascript and HTML4. I have a single page and only two or three text blocks, so I want to avoid a separate style sheet if possible. I am happy to use Android's built in "Droid Serif" But Android ignores this and always defaults to "Droid Sanserif".

Stacoverflow has plenty of advice on adding custom fonts, but I can't find anything on accessing built in fonts.

I define the font-family within a div that surrounds the text. I tried posting the HTML here, but stackoverflow interprets it as formatting and just shows the result, not the code.

My html works fine in all regular browsers, and works fine in Android if I use Google's online fonts, so the structure of the HTML must be fine. But "Droid Serif" and all other font instructions are ignored. Any ideas how to make it behave?

Comment: I don't know how, but if I am there, then I try first java script for the webview. This is for experiment. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried experimenting, but with no joy. I guess I'm stuck with their default san serif font.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean that you have a local font file on the device and want to access it through a WebView?  The best way is through a ContentProvider, it can serve local assets to a webview including fonts.  Here's how to setup the ContentProvider: http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/02/20/serving-android-webview-resources-with-content-providers.html .  There are example there for javascript, image files and css files.  Following the structure from the tutorial, to get a font you would use something like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("content://com.github.browep.lfcp/MyFont.ttf")
}
```

and it would be served from the local filesystem.